# newSng doesn't give correct file path

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a song player and wish to add a feature in which user can add new song by clicking on choose file, but the filepath of the selected song is wrong , it adds something like  "fakepath" to directory. Why is it happening . please help me

> While console logging FilePath variable , It gives result as "C:\fakepath\Levels.mp3"

```js
console.log("Welcome to Spotify ! ")

// Initialize the variables 
let total =7
let songIndex =0;
let masterPlay = document.getElementById('masterPlay')
let myProgressBar = document.getElementById('myProgressBar')
let gif = document.getElementById('gif')
let songItems = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItem'))
let songInfo = document.getElementById('songInfo')
let songItemContainer = document.getElementById('songItemContainer')
let songs =[
    {songName: "GOAT", filePath: "./songs/GOAT.mp3",coverPath: "./covers/cover1.jpg"},
    {songName: "Alone", filePath: "./songs/Alone.mp3",coverPath: "./covers/cover2.jpg"},
    {songName: "Homicide", filePath: "./songs/Homicide.mp3",coverPath: "./covers/cover3.jpg"},
    {songName: "Satisfy", filePath: "./songs/Satisfy.mp3",coverPath: "./covers/cover4.jpg"},
    {songName: "Levels", filePath: "./songs/Levels.mp3",coverPath: "./covers/cover5.jpeg"},
    {songName: "Game Over", filePath: "./songs/GameOver.mp3",coverPath: "./covers/cover6.jpg"},
    {songName: "OG", filePath: "./songs/OG.mp3",coverPath: "./covers/cover7.png"},
];
const searchInput = document.querySelector('[data-search]')

let audioElement = new Audio(songs[0].filePath);
songInfo.innerText = songs[0].songName

var currentTime =""
var play = ""



// declare function 

var convertTime = function(time)
{    
    var mins = Math.floor(time / 60);
    if (mins < 10) {
      mins = '0' + String(mins);
    }
    var secs = Math.floor(time % 60);
    if (secs < 10) {
      secs = '0' + String(secs);
    }

    return mins + ':' + secs;
}

const updtSng = ()=>{
    songItems.forEach((element,i)=>{
        element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = songs[i].coverPath
        element.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText= songs[i].songName
        var audioElement1 = new Audio(songs[i].filePath)
        audioElement1.onloadedmetadata = function(){
    
            document.getElementsByClassName('timeStamp')[i].innerText = convertTime(parseInt(audioElement1.duration))
        }
    
    })

}

updtSng()


const makeAllPlays = ()=>{
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItemPlay')).forEach((element)=>{
        element.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause')
        element.classList.add('fa-circle-play')
    })
}

const makePlay = (element)=>{
    element.classList.remove("fa-circle-pause")
    element.classList.add("fa-circle-play")

}

const makePause = (element)=>{
    element.classList.remove("fa-circle-play")
    element.classList.add("fa-circle-pause")
}



// Listen to events     

audioElement.addEventListener('timeupdate',()=>{
    
    // Update seekbar 
    progress = parseInt((audioElement.currentTime/audioElement.duration)*100)
    myProgressBar.value = progress
    
})

myProgressBar.addEventListener('change',()=>{
    audioElement.currentTime = (myProgressBar.value * audioElement.duration)/100
})



// play and pause 

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItemPlay')).forEach((element)=>{
    element.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        songIndex = parseInt(e.target.id)
        makeAllPlays()
        songInfo.innerText = songs[songIndex].songName
        audioElement.src = songs[songIndex].filePath
        if (play ==0 ||   currentTime<=0){
            audioElement.ontimeupdate = function(){
                currentTime =parseInt(audioElement.currentTime)    
                console.log(parseInt(audioElement.currentTime))
    
            }
            
            audioElement.play();
            makePause(masterPlay)
            makePause(e.target)

            gif.style.opacity = 1
            play =1
            
            
            
            
        }
        
        else  {
            audioElement.pause();
            makePlay(masterPlay)
            makePlay(e.target)

            audioElement.currentTime= currentTime
            gif.style.opacity = 0
            play =0
        }
        
        
    })
})

// play, next & previous

masterPlay.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    if (audioElement.paused || audioElement.currentTime<=0){
        audioElement.play();
        makePause(masterPlay)

        songItemPlay = document.getElementById(songIndex)
        makePause(songItemPlay)
        gif.style.opacity = 1
        
    }
    else{
        audioElement.pause();
        makePlay(masterPlay)

        gif.style.opacity = 0
        songItemPlay = document.getElementById(songIndex)

        makePlay(songItemPlay)
        
    }
})

document.getElementById('previous').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if(songIndex===0){
        songIndex=0
    }
    else{
        songItemPlay = document.getElementById(songIndex)
        makePlay(songItemPlay)
        songIndex -=1
    }
    songItemPlay = document.getElementById(songIndex)
    makePause(songItemPlay)
    makePause(masterPlay)

    songInfo.innerText = songs[songIndex].songName
    audioElement.src = songs[songIndex].filePath
    audioElement.play()
    audioElement.currentTime=0
})
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if(songIndex>=total-1){
        makeAllPlays()
        songIndex=0
    }
    else{
        songItemPlay = document.getElementById(songIndex)
        makePlay(songItemPlay)
        songIndex +=1
    }
    songItemPlay = document.getElementById(songIndex)
    makePause(songItemPlay)
    makePause(masterPlay)

    songInfo.innerText = songs[songIndex].songName
    audioElement.src = songs[songIndex].filePath
    audioElement.play()
    audioElement.currentTime=0
})

// search 

searchInput.addEventListener("input",(e)=>{
    const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase()
    songItems.forEach(song=>{
        const isVisible = song.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(value)
        song.classList.toggle('hide',!isVisible)
        
    })

})


// add new song 

newSng = document.getElementById('inp')

newSng.addEventListener('change',()=>{
    newFilePath = newSng.value
    console.log(newFilePath)
    newSng.name = newFilePath.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop().split('.')[0]
    

    
    songs.push({songName:newSng.name, filePath: newFilePath})
    console.log(songs)
    total+=1
    newDiv= document.createElement("div")   
    newDiv.setAttribute("class","songItem")
    newDiv.innerHTML = ` <img alt=${total} >
    <span class = "songName"></span>
    <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp"></span><i id = ${total-1} class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>`
    
    songItemContainer.append(newDiv)

    updtSng()
    
    
    console.log(newDiv)
    
    
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: antiquewhite;

}

nav{
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

nav ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    height: 9vh;    
    background-color:black ;
    color: white;
}

nav ul li{
    padding-left: 3vw;
}

.brand{
    padding-left: 1vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.brand img {
    width: 3vw;
    height: 5vh;
}

.container{
    min-height: 71vh;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    margin: 3vh auto;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 70%;
    background-image: url(./others/uwp2726170.jpeg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    justify-content: space-between;

}

.bottom{
    position: sticky;
    height: 14vh;
    background-color: black;
    bottom:0;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.icons{
    margin-top:1.5vh ;
}

.icons i{
    cursor: pointer;
}

#myProgressBar{
    width: 80vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px; */
}

.songItem{
    display: flex;
    height: 6vh;
    width: 25vw;
    margin: 1.5vh 2vw;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    border-color: whitesmoke;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-radius: 34px;
    border-width:0.2px ;
}

.songItem:hover{
    background-color: #e2a3e8;
    color: black;
}

.songItem img{
    width: 3vw;
    border-radius: 26px;
}

.timeStamp{
    margin: 0 0.5vw
}

.songList{
    padding: 2vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.songlistplay i{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.songItemContainer{
    margin-top: 8vh;
}

.songInfo{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    position:absolute;
    left: 10vw;
}

.songInfo img{
    width: 3vw;
}

.songInfo img{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in;
}


/* .search-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
} */

#search {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 2vh 4vw;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 6vh;
    width: 20vw;
    background: none;
    color: white;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 4px;
    
}

::placeholder{
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}

.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spotify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="brand"><img src="./others/logo.png" alt="Spotify">Spotify</li>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container">
        
        <div class="songList">
            <h1>Best of NCS</h1>
            <div class="songItemContainer" id = "songItemContainer">
                <div class="songItem">
                    <img alt="1" >
                    <span class = "songName"></span>
                    <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp"></span><i id = "0" class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>
                </div>
                <div class="songItem">
                    <img alt="2" >
                    <span class = "songName"></span>
                    <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp"></span><i id = "1" class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>
                </div>
                <div class="songItem">
                    <img alt="3" >
                    <span class = "songName"></span>
                    <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp"></span><i id = "2" class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>
                </div>
                <div class="songItem">
                    <img alt="4" >
                    <span class = "songName"></span>
                    <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp"></span><i id = "3" class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>
                </div>
                <div class="songItem">
                    <img   alt="5" >
                    <span class = "songName"></span>
                    <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp"></span><i id = "4" class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>
                </div>
                <div class="songItem">
                    <img alt="6" >
                    <span class = "songName">r</span>
                    <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp"></span><i id = "5" class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>
                </div>
                <div class="songItem">
                    <img alt="7" height="44px" width="44px" >
                    <span class = "songName"></span>
                    <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp"></span><i id = "6" class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="songBanner"></div>
        <div class="add"><input type="file" name="" id="inp" ></div>
        <div class="search-wrapper">
            <!-- <label for="search">Search Users</label> -->
            <input type="search" id ="search" placeholder="Seach here....." data-search>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bottom">
        <input type="range" name="range" id="myProgressBar" min ='0' max = "100" value="0">
        <div class="icons">
            <!-- fontawesome icons  -->
            <i class="fa-solid fa-3x fa-backward-step" id="previous"></i>      
            <i class="fa-regular fa-3x fa-circle-play" id="masterPlay"></i>    
            <i class="fa-solid fa-3x fa-forward-step" id="next"></i>      
        </div>
        <div   class="songInfo">
            <img src="./others/playing.gif" id="gif" alt="">  <p id="songInfo"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d76649665f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi. This is the security implementation in browser, the browser is protecting you from accessing your disk or file paths.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly what you are trying to do, there is a problem.
This will run in the browser, but the browser has no access to the computer files, so you cannot use `newFilePath = newSng.value` to link to that path.

there are several similar questions here on stack overflow, like for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

I think you best option would be to use the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications), which allows you to read the content of the file. You can then use this to play the file, instead of a path to the file itself.

[Here](https://www.codewithlinda.com/blog/upload-picture-on-the-web/) there are some example on how to do it.

Beware! Allowing users to upload files into your application may lead to security issues!